# How to get some value from Backbone save success?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to get some value from Backbone save success?
In save success I get 'response' with info I want to use outside the success.
I do: var str = response;
But when I want to use str in another place of code is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Please read [ask] and share the code so that we can help you with it.

Comment: You should show how (where and to what event) you call `save()` and how you want to access the responses value or what part of your code does not work as expected. (Please be precise and don't just dump all your code and say it does not work, limit the code to the relevant parts [or create an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))